# Pythonのforループとbreakをについて教えて下さい。

Tags: python3

こんにちは。Python初心者です。
このコードを実行すると、「1」ではなく、「0」が出力される理由を教えて下さい。

forループの中で、breakを入れ途中でループを抜けるコードを作りたいのですが、
どうしても自分の思うようにいきません。

私は以下のようなコードで、listAというリストに[1, 2, 3]という要素を
入れました。そして、その要素の中から0番目の「1」のみを出力したいと考え、
以下のようなコードを作りました。リストの0番目を出力したらbreakに
移れるようにnumber += 1をコードの中に含めました。そしてnumberが
1になるのでbreakになりループから抜けられるという見込みでした。

しかし、出力されるのが最初に申した通り、「0」になります。「0」という
要素は当リストに入っておりません。理由と改善方法を教えて下さい。

```
listA = [1, 2, 3]
number = 0
for listA[number] in range(0, 3):
    print(listA[number])
    number += 1
    if number == 1:
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 原因(0が表示される)

```
for listA[number] in range(0, 3):
```

のループの最初の処理でlistA[0]に0(※)が格納されています。
　　※　range(0, 3)の初回の値

### 改善

`for listA[number] in range(0, 3):`を以下のように修正すればよいと思います。

```
for i in range(len(listA)):
```